# QtCreator with OpenCV Won't Debug

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, debugging, computer-vision

When debugging a Qt C++-project without including the OpenCV statements, the debbuger won't launch and it always shows a red bar on the lower right.

I created a new Qt-Widgets-project with a QMainWindow and only modified the mainwindow.cpp-file as follows;

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // read an image
//    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(300,200),CV_8UC1);
    int a = 1;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in the `int a = 1;`-line, the debugger launches and stops before this line. If I uncomment the line before that, then the debugger won't launch. In the project file **test.pro**, I added the lines according to https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows as follows:

**test.pro:**

```
...

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include

LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_core451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_highgui451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgproc451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_features2d451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_calib3d451.dll
```

There are no errors and the cv:: Mat data type declarations are found, so I guess that including them works correctly.

How can I get my code to debug correctly?

Comment: dlls aren't libs. those are two different things. libs are needed at compile/link time. dlls are needed at runtime.

Comment: I don't really know in what way this comment could help - sorry. 
The declaration in the .pro-file is just as in the Qt documentation. Did you have a look at the link?

Comment: it's a wiki and at best it contains accidentally working advice. it is not official documentation. a compiler isn't told where to find the dll files, it's told where to find the lib files, so you need to find the lib files and specify those paths instead.